# I'm trying to connect to mongodb Atlas but I keep getting error and can't proceed

Tags: mongodb

My error goes :

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-ts5b5.mongodb.net/test" --username admin-David
MongoDB shell version v4.0.6
Enter password: Cannot get console mode 6
```

I meant to write password there but I can't proceed to password so I can't connect to Atlas at all. Please sort this problem!!

Answer (score 13):

I ran into this same problem today, I was able to log in by including the password in the same statement where the url and username are.

So in your case try doing this:

```
mongo "mongodb+srv://cluster0-ts5b5.mongodb.net/test" --username admin-David --password <yourPasswordHere>
```

That worked for me, hopefully it helps!

MongoDB docs reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-username